# Reordering matrix with a permutation vector but keeping the original size of matrix

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, permutation, reorderlist

I have a simple issue but impossible to fix it. I have a `C_temp` 16x16 matrix (`size = 16`) like this copied from another matrix.

```
C_temp = np.zeros((size, size))                                                                                
C_temp = np.copy(C_in)
```

Then, I have a permutation list (or numpy array, I don't know if it does matter) :

`print('index_reorder =', index_reorder)` gives :

```
index_reorder = ', array([2, 4, 0, 5, 1, 3, 7, 8]))
```

I would like to do permutations indiced by `index_reorder` along `x axis` and `y axis`.

```
      C_temp = np.copy(C_in)
      C_temp = C_temp[:, index_reorder]
      C_temp = C_temp[index_reorder, :]
      C_new = np.copy(C_temp)
```

But unfortunately, the new matrix `C_new` size is reduced to 8x8.

This is not what I would like to get : I want to keep the same size for `C_new` matrix `(16x16)`, i.e doing permutations while keeping the entire size of permuted matrix `C_temp`.

How to perform this global permutation ?

This is called a "permutation in-place" I believe, isn't it ?

**UPDATE 1 :** Here is an example of `C_in` matrix 16x16

```
C_in = ', array([[ 5.39607129e+06,  1.79979372e+06, -2.46370980e+06,
        -1.12590397e+06,  2.54997996e+03, -3.48237530e+02,
         1.77139942e+05,  2.10555125e+04, -2.24912032e+05,
        -9.79292472e+01, -1.63415352e+05, -8.65388775e+01,
        -8.10556705e+04, -6.40511456e+01,  1.31499502e+04,
        -4.80973452e+01],
       [ 1.79979372e+06,  1.85207497e+07, -5.97280544e+06,
        -4.86527342e+05, -9.46833729e+05, -2.10321296e+05,
        -7.71198259e+05, -8.88750203e+04, -1.66150873e+06,
        -3.20782728e+02, -1.45257426e+06, -2.86060423e+02,
        -1.10641471e+06, -2.17539743e+02, -9.34181143e+05,
        -1.77667406e+02],
       [-2.46370980e+06, -5.97280544e+06,  3.36326384e+06,
         5.88733451e+05,  3.35606646e+05,  8.96417015e+04,
         1.12240864e+05,  1.35483472e+04,  6.10023925e+05,
         1.26679014e+02,  5.65166386e+05,  1.21455772e+02,
         4.43234727e+05,  9.80424886e+01,  3.68206009e+05,
         8.44106515e+01],
       [-1.12590397e+06, -4.86527342e+05,  5.88733451e+05,
         3.34731505e+05, -3.26665859e+04, -7.14038524e+03,
        -7.25370986e+04, -8.44842826e+03,  4.40874561e+04,
         2.82933253e+01,  2.77238713e+04,  2.47986977e+01,
         7.27381187e+03,  1.80784440e+01, -1.87787106e+04,
         1.31142301e+01],
       [ 2.54997996e+03, -9.46833729e+05,  3.35606646e+05,
        -3.26665859e+04,  7.90884228e+04,  1.92364617e+04,
         5.66130910e+04,  6.70772964e+03,  1.07063410e+05,
         1.46143888e+01,  9.53013920e+04,  1.33963997e+01,
         7.42574771e+04,  1.04791841e+01,  6.58013341e+04,
         8.95530786e+00],
       [-3.48237530e+02, -2.10321296e+05,  8.96417015e+04,
        -7.14038524e+03,  1.92364617e+04,  4.99000202e+03,
         1.10082611e+04,  1.34941127e+03,  2.41927165e+04,
         3.26733542e+00,  2.31011986e+04,  3.22432044e+00,
         1.88491639e+04,  2.65297382e+00,  1.72802490e+04,
         2.36016813e+00],
       [ 1.77139942e+05, -7.71198259e+05,  1.12240864e+05,
        -7.25370986e+04,  5.66130910e+04,  1.10082611e+04,
         9.36434428e+04,  1.07348807e+04,  6.09534507e+04,
         3.44072173e+00,  5.90764148e+04,  4.26292063e+00,
         5.10904441e+04,  4.37089791e+00,  5.24285786e+04,
         5.06825219e+00],
       [ 2.10555125e+04, -8.88750203e+04,  1.35483472e+04,
        -8.44842826e+03,  6.70772964e+03,  1.34941127e+03,
         1.07348807e+04,  1.48215248e+03,  2.49002654e+03,
         1.40557890e-01,  5.84713359e+03,  4.21925848e-01,
         7.21719030e+03,  6.17446227e-01,  9.39064037e+03,
         9.07789891e-01],
       [-2.24912032e+05, -1.66150873e+06,  6.10023925e+05,
         4.40874561e+04,  1.07063410e+05,  2.41927165e+04,
         6.09534507e+04,  2.49002654e+03,  5.91760033e+05,
         9.77850970e+01,  0.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00,
         0.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00,
         0.00000000e+00],
       [-9.79292472e+01, -3.20782728e+02,  1.26679014e+02,
         2.82933253e+01,  1.46143888e+01,  3.26733542e+00,
         3.44072173e+00,  1.40557890e-01,  9.77850970e+01,
         2.42137019e-02,  0.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00,
         0.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00,
         0.00000000e+00],
       [-1.63415352e+05, -1.45257426e+06,  5.65166386e+05,
         2.77238713e+04,  9.53013920e+04,  2.31011986e+04,
         5.90764148e+04,  5.84713359e+03,  0.00000000e+00,
         0.00000000e+00,  4.84422452e+05,  8.24104281e+01,
         0.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00,
         0.00000000e+00],
       [-8.65388775e+01, -2.86060423e+02,  1.21455772e+02,
         2.47986977e+01,  1.33963997e+01,  3.22432044e+00,
         4.26292063e+00,  4.21925848e-01,  0.00000000e+00,
         0.00000000e+00,  8.24104281e+01,  2.11226210e-02,
         0.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00,
         0.00000000e+00],
       [-8.10556705e+04, -1.10641471e+06,  4.43234727e+05,
         7.27381187e+03,  7.42574771e+04,  1.88491639e+04,
         5.10904441e+04,  7.21719030e+03,  0.00000000e+00,
         0.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00,
         3.50093152e+05,  6.00111232e+01,  0.00000000e+00,
         0.00000000e+00],
       [-6.40511456e+01, -2.17539743e+02,  9.80424886e+01,
         1.80784440e+01,  1.04791841e+01,  2.65297382e+00,
         4.37089791e+00,  6.17446227e-01,  0.00000000e+00,
         0.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00,
         6.00111232e+01,  1.57248915e-02,  0.00000000e+00,
         0.00000000e+00],
       [ 1.31499502e+04, -9.34181143e+05,  3.68206009e+05,
        -1.87787106e+04,  6.58013341e+04,  1.72802490e+04,
         5.24285786e+04,  9.39064037e+03,  0.00000000e+00,
         0.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00,
         0.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00,  2.83150690e+05,
         4.74239664e+01],
       [-4.80973452e+01, -1.77667406e+02,  8.44106515e+01,
         1.31142301e+01,  8.95530786e+00,  2.36016813e+00,
         5.06825219e+00,  9.07789891e-01,  0.00000000e+00,
         0.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00,
         0.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00,  4.74239664e+01,
         1.26116519e-02]]))
```

and the output `C_new` matrix :

```
C_new = ', array([[ 3.36326384e+06,  3.35606646e+05, -2.46370980e+06,
         8.96417015e+04, -5.97280544e+06,  5.88733451e+05,
         1.35483472e+04,  6.10023925e+05],
       [ 3.35606646e+05,  7.90884228e+04,  2.54997996e+03,
         1.92364617e+04, -9.46833729e+05, -3.26665859e+04,
         6.70772964e+03,  1.07063410e+05],
       [-2.46370980e+06,  2.54997996e+03,  5.39607129e+06,
        -3.48237530e+02,  1.79979372e+06, -1.12590397e+06,
         2.10555125e+04, -2.24912032e+05],
       [ 8.96417015e+04,  1.92364617e+04, -3.48237530e+02,
         4.99000202e+03, -2.10321296e+05, -7.14038524e+03,
         1.34941127e+03,  2.41927165e+04],
       [-5.97280544e+06, -9.46833729e+05,  1.79979372e+06,
        -2.10321296e+05,  1.85207497e+07, -4.86527342e+05,
        -8.88750203e+04, -1.66150873e+06],
       [ 5.88733451e+05, -3.26665859e+04, -1.12590397e+06,
        -7.14038524e+03, -4.86527342e+05,  3.34731505e+05,
        -8.44842826e+03,  4.40874561e+04],
       [ 1.35483472e+04,  6.70772964e+03,  2.10555125e+04,
         1.34941127e+03, -8.88750203e+04, -8.44842826e+03,
         1.48215248e+03,  2.49002654e+03],
       [ 6.10023925e+05,  1.07063410e+05, -2.24912032e+05,
         2.41927165e+04, -1.66150873e+06,  4.40874561e+04,
         2.49002654e+03,  5.91760033e+05]]))
```

I just want to swap rows/columns (i.e looks like permutations ?) as a function of `index_reorder` vector of rows/columns.

Comment: In your example, you have a permutation of the n-first elements. Is it guaranteed to be always like this? If not, how would you like the result to look like in the case, that e.g. `index_reorder == [4,7, 2]`

Comment: Sorry, I didn't explain vrery well my first question, so I have reformated it in order to be as much explicit as possible. Don't hesitate to let me a comment if you don't understand. If you can't see a solution, then I will start a bounty.

Comment: Could you add sample for `C_in` as well? Or what's its shape?

Comment: It is still not fully clear to me, how you would like the result to look like. In your current example, where should the elements for which the permutation is not defined be placed? The original position is not always possible, since e.g. 6 is missing from your "permutation", so its original position is taken. Could you provide a full example for a smaller case? Maybe how you would like the following to look like:
`C_in = [ [1,2,3,4] [5,6,7,8] [9,10,11,12] [13,14,15,16] ]`
and
`index_reorder = [0,2]`

Comment: You are indexing with an indexing array that has a length of 8 across both rows and cols, hence o/p is 8x8. What's wrong with that? Do you want to keep the non-indexed ones from `C_in` to be unchanged in the output instead?

Comment: I would like to  select all entire rows/columns indicated by permutation vector. for  example, for the first index equaal to  '2", I want to seelct all the third columns   16x1 and the same behavior for other indices of permutatons vectors, as well for rows (1x16) than for columns (16x1)  when I do `C_temp = C_temp[:, index_reorder] and  C_temp = C_temp[index_reorder,:]`

Comment: @Divakar Indeed, I want to  select entire row/column referenced by the index of "permutation vector" (in my case, first, I want to swap columns by `C_temp[:, index_reorder]` and then  rows by `C_temp = C_temp[index_reorder,:]`

Comment: @youpilat13 Don't think you are getting my point. Since `index_reorder` is of length `8`, so when you do `C_temp[:, index_reorder]`. It selects those specific 8 columns off `C_temp` and hence `C_temp[:, index_reorder]` becomes `16x8`  and similarly for the row indexing. Think you should read up on docs - https://numpy.org/doc/1.18/reference/arrays.indexing.html#integer-array-indexing

Comment: a kind of "direct inline" swapping is not possible ? Am I obliged to use a 16 elements "permutation vector" ?

Comment: @youpilat13 Swapping what with what? For swapping we need two arrays I presume? Seems `index_reorder` is one of the arrays, right? What's the other one?

Comment: @Divakar no, you didn't grasp the right thing, `index_reorder`is the vector of indices containing the indices of of rows/columns to swap.

Comment: Indeed, swapping assumes 2 arrays, I should rather call this operation as a permutation since I want to do multiple swapping in the same time

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you found out yourself, the problem is, that `index_reorder` does only contain the reordered elements.

The solution is, to extend it to a full permutation off all elements. If the elements should stay in place, just write their index at their old position so they will stay.

E.g.:

```
index_reorder = [2, 4, 0, 5, 1, 3, 7, 8]
```

should be transformed to:

```
full_reorder = [2, 4, 0, 5, 1, 3, 7, 8, 6, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15]
```

Note, that 9->9, 10->10, 11->11.... That way, they are not moved and not lost. There would be other `full_reorders` thinkable, and their choice only depends on your preference. One, that you might prefer is `[2, 4, 0, 5, 1, 3, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15]`. Here 6->6 and the original permutation is stretched around it.

The changed reorder as given in the first example can be achieved as followed:

```
all_indices = np.array(range(16))
other_indices = np.setdiff1d(all_indices, index_reorder)
full_reorder = np.concatenate([index_reorder, other_indices])
```

And then continue as you have done:

```
C_temp = np.copy(C_in)
C_temp = C_temp[:, full_reorder]
C_temp = C_temp[full_reorder, :]
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I wouldn't like to have the remaining elements at the end, I just want to update the reordering while keeping the other elements at their place, you understand ?

Comment: And where do you want to have the element if another is set to its original position but no new position was defined for it?

Comment: So, for example: how would you like ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'] to look like, if the reordering ist [3,2]

Comment: I think that I have to use a mask (of boolean) to perform update for some values and let the others : what do you think about ?

Comment: I'm still not entirely sure what result would like to see. Could you take a look at the comment under the question?

Comment: Sorry to bore you again but I have reformulated my initial question, you can see it in the OP.

Comment: I will take a look at it tomorrow

Comment: I put an example of input matrix and the result which is a 8x8 matrix and not 16x16

Comment: I still need to know what exactly you would like to happen with the other columns/rows. Column/row 6 e.g. is now (partially) taken by other elements, but there is no new position for it defined in your current permutation.

Comment: I updated my answer, but until I know what you want the result to look like, I can only guess how to extend the partial permutation to a full permutation, but I'm certain that this is, would you should generally do.

Comment: Thank you so much ! I don't want to bore you but I would like here or in the context of a new post why I have still difficulties to deal with the index 6 for row/colum of my matrix to reorder. It's a little bit tricky to explain but you may give some clarification about this issue. I keep you informed. Regards

Comment: Sure. I will be happy to help. The most important thing is that you decide on how you would like the result to look like. Everything else, I can help you with. If you create a new post make sure to link it, so I will find it.